# Looping results in this error in jbpm 6.0 RC2

Tags: java, jbpm

Following is the error I get whenever I try to call loop, it shows some result initially but then it results in following error,

```
at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.ActionNodeInstance.internalTrigger(ActionNodeInstance.java:57)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:155)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:338)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(NodeInstanceImpl.java:297)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's really funny, you didn't paste the error.. just where it is happening.. so with that amount of information is really difficult to help you.